# Is this a 'Post hoc ergo propter hoc' Fallacy?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation

Is this a Post hoc ergo propter hoc fallacy?
'The most intense lightning storm ever recorded was followed by many numerous
Bushfires; the lightning must have caused them.'

and why?

Thanks for any answers, im really struggling with this.

Comment: [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation)

Comment: Correct; also [Post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) will do.

Comment: The thing is, lightning storm are indeed known to cause bushfires, so as David Blomstrom says below, only the "must" is too much (and even then, "must" only denotes very high certainty, not 100%). Post hoc ergo propter hoc would more likely be something with no obvious causation link, like "I won the lottery right after dumping my girl friend, ergo she must have been giving me bad luck all this time".